# Powershell - Passing multiple arraylists to Invoke-Command block

Tags: powershell, arraylist, invoke-command

I am trying to write a powershell script that will tell me if a computer in my network is on or off, and if it is on, if there is anyone logged in. Currently I have:

```
# Create some empty arraylists                                                               
$availablecomputers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$unavailablecomputers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$usersloggedon = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#Check connectivity for each machine via Test-WSMan
foreach ($computer in $restartcomputerlist)
{
    try 
    {
    Test-WSMan -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop |out-null
    Invoke-Command `
    -ComputerName  $computer `
    -ScriptBlock `
    {
        if
        ((Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).username -like "AD\*")
        {
            $args[0] += $computer
        }
        else 
        {
            $args[1] += $computer
        }
    } `
    -ArgumentList (,$usersloggedon), (,$availablecomputers)
    }
    catch 
    {
    $unavailablecomputers += $computer 
    }
}
```

So far, if the computer is not on, it works correctly. However, if it is on, $computer won't be added to $usersloggedon or $availablecomputers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$args` only exist in the context of the ScriptBlock, assigning to it won't modify or "write back to" the variables you pass as arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mathias is correct; variables you pass into the scriptblock are passed by value (serialized), not by reference, so you can't update them and change the original object.

To return values from the scriptblock, use `Write-Object` or just simply "use" the value (`Write-Object $env:COMPUTERNAME` is the same as just doing `$env:COMPUTERNAME`).

For your specific situation, consider returning an object that contains the information you want:

```powershell
$computers = @()

#Check connectivity for each machine via Test-WSMan
foreach ($computer in $restartcomputerlist)
{
    try 
    {
    Test-WSMan -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop |out-null
    $computers += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        $props = @{
            Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            Available = $true
            UsersLoggedOn = ((Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).username -like "AD\*")
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $props
    }
    }
    catch 
    {
    $props = @{
        Name = $computer
        Available = $false
        UsersLoggedOn = $false
    }
    $computers += New-Object PSObject -Property $props 
    }
}
$computers # You can now use this with Select-Object, Sort-Object, Format-* etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I figured it was passed by value, so I was trying to figure out if there was a way to make it pass by reference. Your code worked beautifully, except that the -Properties part had to be changed to -Property.

Comment: D'oh, that's what I get for not testing the code before posting it! (Fixed)